# Download and locally store all emails from all mailboxes on Office365?

Tags: backup, microsoft-office-365

We have a business that uses Office365 and we want to be able to save all the emails locally. I found a [thread on Office365 community](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/160/t/8935.aspx) pertaining to this and basically it was stated that there is no direct way of accomplishing this. I am curious if anyone has considered this and if there is a good method for storing these emails locally, even if it's some nifty PowerShell programming. All I've come up with is having a master mailbox which can view all mailboxes, and just have it sync and archive locally to the computer. I have not tried this yet, as the storage file sounds like it will be huge, so this does not seem like a fantastic idea and I'm open to any suggestions!

Comment: I can't help, but to be clear, what's your goal here? Is it for archival purposes, or for users to access?

Comment: Sorry, that's a good point. It's simply for local archiving and the occasional need to step back in time and look up an old email from the administrative point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question.  We ran into a problem with O365 many months ago where the AD sync tool caused all of our mailboxes to be deleted.  It took close to a week for MSFT to restore all of the mailboxes for us.  Either way they recommend having off-site backups as they are ultimately not responsible for data loss if it happens, other than what is in the SLA.

We worked with MessageOps as they have a [tool for downloading mailboxes](http://www.messageops.com/software/office-365-tools-and-utilities/office-365-exchange-migrator) administratively that works pretty well.  It's free if you list them as your partner of record in O365.

Comment: Awesome, regardless they have a bunch of cool little utilities and they do offer consulting if you have a need for it.

Comment: Just as an update, I have tried this software and simply cannot get it to work-- I found it very error prone and rather disappointing. I really wanted it to work :-\

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link, it is the export tool within O365

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/export-or-back-up-messages-calendar-tasks-and-contacts-HA102809683.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.